# Does C++ have move and delete semantics?

Tags: c++, scope, move-semantics, delete-operator, lifetime

Is it possible to create disposable variables in C++ without any funky business with the braces?

Here is an example of what I want to achieve:

```
const float _phiTemp  = atan2(tan(cluster.beta), tan(cluster.alpha));
const float phi       = HALF_PI - std::abs(HALF_PI - std::abs(_phiTemp));
// After running this code I want _phiTemp to be unaccessible, and the
// compiler to send an error if I ever try
```

Here is a long and ugly implementation of what I want:

```
const float phi = 0;
{
     const float _phiTemp  = atan2(tan(cluster.beta), tan(cluster.alpha));
     float& phiRef = const_cast<float&> phi;
     phiRef = HALF_PI - std::abs(HALF_PI - std::abs(std::move(_phiTemp)));
}
// _phiTemp is disposed and phi is a const, and safely used in the calculation
// through std::move()
```

Am I missing something? Is there no "instant" variable disposal in C++?

Comment: "*Is there no "instant" variable disposal in c++?*" Yes there is, and you already created an example of it. Use brackets to indicate scope, scope indicates lifetime. Nothing ugly about it.

Comment: Well, by instant I mean it as "remove variable from stack in the current scope" (+make it so that the compiler knows that the variable is no more).

Comment: Casting away that const from `phi` and assigning through it has undefined behaviour.

Comment: "Well, by instant I mean it as "remove variable from stack in the current scope"" No, and I don't see why it would be useful, if you wan't objects that you can destroy dynamically, then just create them dynamically.

Comment: Use a function instead of a temporary variable?  You cannot just remove a variable with automatic storage duration since it's lifetime is bound to its scope.  That is what makes it automatic.

Comment: I'm not sure what the purpose or value of what you are trying to achieve is. You could use a lamda to return the calculation of `_phiTemp` if you really don't want a lingering variable, or just enclose the entire thing within the std::abs statement. Again though, not sure what you are trying to achieve here. Sounds like over-complicating.

Comment: @djgandy:  As I see it the desiderata are: a) desiring a compiler error if other code refers to the temporary; b) desiring a compiler error if any subsequent attempt is made to modify it.  Neither of those seem unreasonable.

Comment: @MartinBonner: I guess I want the underlying motivation behind this. e.g. To stop programmers making mistakes. What would be the advantage of this behaviour considering how finite the scope of the temporary is? A misbehaving programmer can simply copy and paste the expression again if they really want to and the law of unintended consequences has just granted you a slower program. Your second point is covered by const. In this example if `phi` could just be initialised in a single statement and probably from a named function with a nice explanation of what it's actually doing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The long and ugly implementation is also undefined behaviour; the write to `phiRef` is a write to a variable defined as const.

The best you can do is to write a function to calculate `phi` - if you want to do this inline, you could write a lambda:

```
const float phi = [&cluster]{
    const float phiTemp  = atan2(tan(cluster.beta), tan(cluster.alpha)); 
    return HALF_PI - std::abs(HALF_PI - std::abs(phiTemp));
}();
```

... but it's still pretty ugly. I don't think C++ offers this functionality.

Comment: I think an IIFE lambda is the best C++11 solution for short code (this is the one I use in real code). For pre-C++11 and for longer code, simply use a separate named function

Answer (score 1):

[Martin Bonner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40846699/3233393) is on the right track : a lambda works very well as a "scope-with-`return`" where you can declare helper variables as you please. Below is what I have made in my personal toolkit to take it one step further:

```
namespace initBlock_detail {
    struct tag { };

    template <class F>
    decltype(auto) operator * (tag, F &&f) {
        return std::forward<F>(f)();
    }
}

#define glk_initBlock \
    glk::initBlock_detail::tag{} * [&]() -> decltype(auto)
```

The calling syntax looks like:

```
const float phi = glk_initBlock {
    const float phiTemp  = atan2(tan(cluster.beta), tan(cluster.alpha)); 
    return HALF_PI - std::abs(HALF_PI - std::abs(phiTemp));
};
```

Comment: Eep!  So you call the lambda by passing it to a magic `operator *` (which calls it and returns the result).  The point this being that you don't need the trailing `()` after the block.  That strikes me as very clever ... but I am not sure if it is *too* clever or not.

Comment: @MartinBonner I take no credit for this trick -- I leaned it from Andrei Alexandrescu's talk about his `ScopeGuard`. But I do love it :)

Answer (score -1):

I think what you want is a temporary variable. i.e. Don't name your intermediate value.

```
const float phi = HALF_PI - std::abs(
    HALF_PI - std::abs(
        atan2(
            tan(cluster.beta)
            , tan(cluster.alpha)
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: That works in this example (although a bit hard to read).  It doesn't work if the second expression was `const float phi = 2*square(_phiTemp) + _phiTemp - 1;` (for example)

Comment: This fails for two reasons: 
1. it defeats the purpose of separating the calculations, and destroys readibility
2. you cannot reuse the same variable without calculating it from scratch, eg. a * f(a) would mean, that one would need to calculate a twice.

Comment: The readability argument is subjective; I don't find anything particularly readable about a temporary intermediate variable that is only used once. I think it is clearer to only declare the variables you need, as in your second case where you need the value twice.

Comment: This answer does capture the semantics you were looking for. If you don't like this answer I'm pretty sure the IIFE answers are the only other ones that get you the same semantics. An intermediate variable that is named *will* survive to the end of its scope; only an unnamed temporary will go away at the end of a line.